# Blob triggered Azure function doesn't work deployed but works locally, and no sign of any error

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

Here's my Azure function made with VS2017 15.6.0 Preview 1.1 - https://github.com/alvipeo/azfunc. It perfectly works when I run it locally with VS.

I created a CI/CD pipeline with VSTS. No errors there too, all deployed successfully.

I set all settings in Azure, so it should work when deployed. But it doesn't. And what's more, I see NO SIGN of errors or any log records anywhere (but I enabled everything in the Diagnostics and I have App Insights).

Comment: What does **But it doesn't** mean? Would you mind sharing more info about that? According to your code
 `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TwilioAccSid")`,Have you added the "TwilioAccSid" in the [Azure function Appsetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings)?

Comment: Yes, ALL settings are set correctly.

Comment: Aren't you by accident running local and remote instances at the same time with same connection strings?

Comment: `[StorageAccount("OfficePicsStorage")]` - `OfficePicsStorage` is the name of storage account or name of application setting which holds connection string to storage account?

Comment: Perhaps you could check App Service Editor whether the package is deployed correctly - the wwwroot directory should have the same contents as `your_project_root/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/publish` after you run `dotnet publish`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Microsoft engineers, it's solved. Here's what needs to be done:

1. When function is built in VS2017 for .NET Core 2.0 and deployed with VSTS, for some reason runtime version in Azure is set to 1. But when I run it locally I see the runtime version = 2. So you need to set in Azure this setting `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION=~2`
2. When you use blob triggered Azure Function you can't use Blob-only Storage accounts (and I used the one). You have to use General Purpose storage account.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. I see my Portal app settings has FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION=beta. I tried using ~2 but the blob trigger is still not firing. Any other tips to check? I've been at this for quite a bit.